# Mathematica: call a function inside itself and manage factors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, algebra

I am trying to create a program that handles a operators algebra, where the operators don't have a explicit representation.
This implies that I have to define a lot of symbols and parametric functions to keep track of what has been done.

I have two kinds of operators: V^+ and V^-.

The algebra reads:
[V^+(a),V^+(b)]=I X[a,b] V^+(a+b) 
[V^-(a),V^-(b)]=I Xbar[a,b] V^-(a+b) 
Note:("a+b" is not a sum. It's the union of two sets of legs in a Feynman diagram)

Then we have: V^+(a)V^+(b)=I X[a,b]V^+(a|b)
with, of course, V^+(a|b)+V^+(b|a)=V^+(a+b).

X and Xbar are the structure constants and are antisymmetric in the two arguments.

Then we have to define:
V^+(a|b)*V^+/-(c|d)=I X[b,c+d]V^+/-(a+b+c|d)
V^-(a|b)*V^+/-(c|d)=I Xbar[b,c+d]V^+/-(a+b+c|d)

where it's important to define also: V^+/-(a)=V^+/-(0|a).

So, in mathematica I defined up to now the commutator and the product of V's containing things like a|b.
The main problem appears when I want to calculate structures where I have commutators of commutators.
Here is the relevant part of the code:
**Structure constants:**

```
XX[A_, B_] := If[A < B, X[A, B], -X[B, A]]
XXb[A_, B_] := If[A < B, Xb[A, B], -Xb[B, A]]
```

This is done to implement the antisymmetry and facilitate simplification.
**Product with vertical bar objects**

```
PB[V[VB[A_,B_],K_],V[VB[C_,D_],PD_]] :=If[K == 1,I*XX[B,piu[C,D]]V[VB[piu[A,B,C],D],PD],I*XXb[B,piu[C,D]]V[VB[piu[A,B,C],D],PD]]
```

where I used the function "piu" which stands just for the union of legs as in "a+b"(=piu[a,b]).

```
piu[A_, B_] := If[A != 0, If[B != 0, pi[A, B], A], If[B != 0, B, 0]]

piu[A_, B_, C_] := If[A != 0,If[B != 0, If[C != 0, pi[A, B, C], pi[A, B]],If[C != 0,pi[A, C], A]], If[B != 0, If[C != 0, pi[B, C], B], If[C != 0, C, 0]]]
```

The second argument in V can be 0 or 1 and stands just for the "+"(1) or "-"(0).

Then **the commutators**:

```
Comm[V[vb[A_, B_], K_], V[vb[C_, D_], M_]] := PB[V[VB[A, B], K], V[VB[C, D], M]]-PB[V[VB[C, D], M], V[VB[A, B], K]]
Comm[V[vb[A_, B_], K_], V[[piu[C_, D_], E_], M_]] :=PB[V[VB[A, B], K], V[VB[C, D], M]]-PB[V[VB[C, D], M], V[VB[A, B], K]]
```

where I directly used the "0|a" way of writing "a" to avoid ambiguities and where I defined also the special case where one of the arguments is the sum of other two.

Finally, I created a set of rules to simplify stuff and give me the correct results:
**Rules**

```
RC = {
VB[A_, B_] :> vb[A, B],
vb[A_, pi[B_, C_]] :> If[A != 0, vb[A, pi[B, C]], vb[0, pi[B, C]]],
vb[A_, B_] :> If[A != 0, If[B != 0, vb[A, B], vb[A]], If[B != 0, vb[B], 0]],
VB[Null, A_] :> vb[A],
(V[vb[A_, B_], K_] + V[vb[B_, A_], K_]) :> V[vb[0, piu[A, B]], K]
}
```

I apply the rules using:

```
SimplifyRC[expr_]:=Simplify[expr]//.RC
```

To give you an example of what happens, this is the result for a simple commutator:
    SimplifyRC[Comm[V[VB[0, 1], 1], V[VB[0, 2], 1]]]

```
 Out= I V[vb[0, pi[1, 2]], 1] X[1, 2]
```

Up to now everything is fine.

However the goal of the program is to calculate more complex structures with commutators of commutators.

My question is: how do I handle the factors (I, X[a,b], Xbar[a,b]) coming out of commutators, inside the new commutators?
I tried defining some rules to say that the function should be bilinear in the two arguments, but this works just once and as soon as I call the function more than once inside itself, the problem reappears.

Example:

```
SimplifyRC[Comm[V[VB[0, 1], 1], Comm[V[VB[0, 2], 1], V[VB[0, 3], 1]]]]

Out= Comm[V[vb[1], 1], I V[vb[0, pi[2, 3]], 1] X[2, 3]]
```

This can be handled easily by setting a rule of substitution.
However as soon as I would go to

```
SimplifyRC[Comm[V[VB[0, 1], 1],Comm[V[VB[0, 1], 2], Comm[V[VB[0, 3], 1], V[VB[0, 4], 1]]]]]
```

the problem would pop up again cause inside the new commutator I would have something like "X[a,b]X[c,d]" and the rule wouldn't work anymore.

Is there a smart way to implement a rule that takes care of that and brings out of the commutator whatever it's not a V operator?

I hope this is clear enough. The code is messy, but due to the lack of a explicit representation for the operators, one has to define all those functions and symbols to keep track of operations.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, that tells me it's not clear.
Well, I'll wait a bit more. Then in case it's not understandable, I will rewrite it removing the physics (for me it was important to put it in, cause I have to avoid troubles with those rules in case I implement something new).

Comment: +1ed you seems to be a genius.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: [This conference talk](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ?ev=prf_pub) has a section on handling commutators, pulling out scalars, and the like. Also available as a Mathematica notebook at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/